# generate row number by using variable in mssql

Tags: sql-server, variables

In MYSQL, I could use variable to generate the row number like below:

```
SET @num=0;
SELECT @num:=@num+1 rownum,id FROM test;
```

How should I do this in MSSQL? I tried below code:

```
DECLARE @num int
SET @num=0;
SELECT @num=@num+1 ,id FROM test;
```

then I got the error message:

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be
> combined with data-retrieval operations.

I know there're some built-in functions in mssql to generate the row number, but I'd like to know how to use variables in this case to solve the issue.

Appreciate if someone could help on this. :)

Comment: The row number function you're looking for is called [`row_number()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Why do you want to assign each row number to a local variable? You can't combine variable assignment and a select like that, as the error message says, and what value do you expect the variable to hold at "the end"? Are you just trying to _seed_ the start of the sequence?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for the comment. Actually I was just being curious, why this assignment could work on MySQL but not on MSSQL. Windowing functions are quite powerful, but using variables seems more convenient when the conditions become more complicated.(adding different values to local variable according to different conditions).  MySQL looks quite flexible on this so I wonder how does this work in MSSQL.

Comment: I highly doubt there is much you can accomplish in MySQL that you can't accomplish in SQL Server, it's just a matter of understanding _exactly_ what you're trying to accomplish (I don't know what "more complicated conditions" mean) and figuring out how the syntax differs between the two (or any two, really) platforms. If you can be more specific about what you're _actually_ trying to do, you will probably get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you can't do variable assignment in a select statement that also does data retrieval.

You can assign a variable using a select statement...

```
declare @myInt int;
select @myvariable = 1; -- works just like "set" in this case
```

And you can do data retrieval...

```
select someColumn from MyTable
```

But not both at the same time.

You *can* assign a value to a variable when selecting from a table, as long as you don't *also* select columns that don't get assigned to variables.

```
declare @myInt int;
select  @myInt = myIntColumn from MyTable
```

If MyTable has a lot of rows in it, it's not clear which row will be used to populate the value of `@myInt`. SQL is "allowed" to pick any row it wants.

Of course, in your case that doesn't matter, since you're assigning a literal value to the variable. You *can* do this, where by "can", I mean the syntax won't be rejected:

```
declare @myInt int = 0;
select  @myInt = @myInt + 1
from    MyTable
```

**But don't do this.** It's an interesting quirk, which I am showing it to you with the good faith assumption that you won't use it. It is not supported and should not be relied upon.

Jeff Moden wrote an [article](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/solving-the-running-total-and-ordinal-rank-problems-rewritten) about this where he goes over the dangers.

But don't do it even if you follow his rules.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By any chance you know why MYSQL could assign values to variables along with data-retrieval operations?

Comment: @JessieYutingC I don't think there's much we can say about that other than making guesses, it's just how the engine has been built by the programmers who built it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a rownum based on the variable value, you can do that by updating the value in the table like below:

```
drop table if exists #t 
create table #t (id int, rownum int)

insert #t(id) select 100
insert #t(id) select 200
insert #t(id) select 300
insert #t(id) select 400

declare @i int
set @i = 0
update #t set rownum = @i, @i = @i + 1

select * from #t
order by rownum
```